# How can I Create a Expression.Property of a child object

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, expression, func

normally I create an expresion in this way.

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object1), "x");

string Name = "property1";

MemberExpression left = Expression.Property(pe, (object1).GetProperty(Name));
```

it produces `left = x => x.property1`

I need to know how can I produce

`left = x => x.Object2.property1`

if Name = "Object2.property1"; and object2 is a child to object1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 39):

I don't quite understand what you want. Is it a property chain (say: x.Prop1.Prop2)?

```
var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object1));
var property1 = typeof(object1).GetProperty(Name1);
var property2 = property1.PropertyType.GetProperty(Name2);
var inner = Expression.Property(pe, property1);
var outer = Expression.Property(inner, property2);
```

Comment: Thanks actually this is what I needed. I can't vote yet. but this is the answer

Comment: Can you set an answer to your own question as valid?