# Building OrderBy-expression at runtime by property-name which can be nested

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression, expression-trees

How can I dynamically build an order-by expression when only knowing the name of the property (or even the name of a sub-property)?

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
dbResult = // some database-query as IQueryable<TSource> which is not yet executed;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.OrderBy)) { // the user want's to group the results
    var grouped = dbResult.GroupBy(/* this should be build dynamically */);
}
```

I need something to start with as `GroupBy` is awaiting a `Func<TSource, TKey>` but I only know `TKey` at runtime which can be string, int or even a Guid.

The user could pass something like "Country.Name" to the `request.OrderBy` property which means the results should be grouped by a sub-property (sub-select), the name of a country.

I think ExpressionTrees is the way to go here but I'm stuck before even getting started as I don't know how to handle the unknown `Type` as well as the option to group by a property of a sub-select/sub-property.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488391/building-an-orderby-expression-using-the-name-of-a-property?rq=1

Comment: @IanMercer: Working for properties of the main-select, but not for sub-properties, e.g. Country.Name as it throws an Exception `Instance property 'Country.Name' is not defined for type 'CountrySelect'`

Comment: You need to use `Expression.Property` on each property in a chain. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439218/how-can-i-create-a-expression-property-of-a-child-object

Comment: Are you seeking for `OrderBy` (as stated in the post title) or `GroupBy`?

Comment: @IvanStoev 'GroupBy'. But OrderBy would for sure be the next step with same requirements

Comment: `OrderBy` is easy because it doesn't change the element type of the `IQueryable<T>`. But the result of `GroupBy` is `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`, and you don't have `TKey`, so what is the expected result type - `IQueryable<???>`? I mean, building the expression is not hard, but what you will do with the result? It could be non generic `IQueryable`, but it's not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can build dynamically a `GroupBy` expression/query:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable GroupByMember(this IQueryable source, string memberPath)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");
        var member = memberPath.Split('.')
            .Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(member, parameter);
        var groupByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "GroupBy",
            new Type[] { parameter.Type, member.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(groupByCall);
    }
}
```

The problem is though that there is no good generic way of representing the result. And working with non generic `IQueryable` / `IEnumerable` is not easy because almost all LINQ methods operate on generic interfaces. Especially with `IQueryable` you'll find that you need creating more and more methods like this, so you might consider using [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) package.