# Why does this Linq method accepts parameters of type Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees, iqueryable

I found this method in other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246515/building-orderby-expression-at-runtime-by-property-name-which-can-be-nested), and I pretty much understand what's going on, except for the 4th line:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByMember<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string memberPath)
{
    var expression = source.Expression;

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");

    string[] paths = memberPath.Split('.');

    /*****************HERE*******************/

    var member = paths.Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);

    /****************************************/




    var selector = Expression.Lambda(member, parameter);
    var orderByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy",
        new Type[] { parameter.Type, member.Type },
        expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderByCall);
}
```

Why does `IEnumerable<string>.Aggregate` accepts an `Expression` and a `MemberExpression`?

None of the overloads of Aggregate seem to match this call

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.6.2

Since I don't have a clue what's hapenning there, could you please explain?

Comment: So the arrays implement IQueryable?

Comment: Oops! I brainfarted. The `parameter` is the seed, and the `PropertyOrField` is the accumulator. It is calling this [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.6.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does IEnumerable.Aggregate accepts an `Expression` and a `MemberExpression`?

The second argument passed to `Aggregate` is *not* a `MemberExpression`! Look carefully!

[`Expression.PropertyOrField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.propertyorfield?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_PropertyOrField_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_String_) is not a property. It is a method. Since there are no brackets at the end, you are not calling it. `Expression.PropertyOrField` represents a method group here.

`Expression.PropertyOrField` accepts an `Expression` and a `string` and returns a `MemberExpression`, so it can be represented by the delegate type `Func<Expression, string, MemberExpression>`. And the first argument is of type `Expression`, so you are essentially calling:

```
Aggregate(Expression, Func<Expression, string, MemberExpression>)
```

This matches the signature of this [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.6.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__) of `Aggregate`:

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate> (
    this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    TAccumulate seed, 
    Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate> func);
```

`TAccumulate` is `Expression` and `TSource` is `string`.

As for what this line is doing on a high-level, well, I'm sure you've figured out by now. It converts the string `memberPath`, which might look something like this:

```
w.x.y.z
```

into an `Expression` object that represents that expression.